InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type ' ' while attempting to activate ' '
The second day I can not solve the problem in the project: Error in requests GET/POST.

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'RESTfull.Infrastructure.Interfaces.IStudentRepository' while attempting to activate 'RESTfull.API.Controllers.StudentController'.

I would be very grateful for help in indicating where I have a mistake!
For educational purposes, I make applications for recording attendance of classes
The solution consists of three projects API, Domain, Infrastructure.
I created a data model, configured the migration, it is executed successfully and creates empty tables for now (this is visible through the SQL object browser)
Next, I began to develop repositories, controllers and interfaces.
Started with the entity "Students"
Created files:
StudentRepository:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RESTfull.Domain.Model;
using RESTfull.Infrastructure.Data;
using RESTfull.Infrastructure.Interfaces;

namespace RESTfull.Infrastructure.Repositories
{
    public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository
    {
        private readonly Context _context;

        public StudentRepository(Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Student>> GetAllStudentsAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Students.Include(s => s.Group).ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<Student> GetStudentByIdAsync(int studentId)
        {
            return await _context.Students.Include(s => s.Group).FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.StudentId == studentId);
        }

        public async Task<Student> AddStudentAsync(Student student)
        {
            _context.Students.Add(student);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return student;
        }

        public async Task<Student> UpdateStudentAsync(Student student)
        {
            _context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return student;
        }

        public async Task<Student> DeleteStudentAsync(int studentId)
        {
            var student = await _context.Students.FindAsync(studentId);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            _context.Students.Remove(student);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return student;
        }
    }
}

StudentController:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RESTfull.Domain.Model;
using RESTfull.Infrastructure.Interfaces;
using RESTfull.Infrastructure.Repositories;

namespace RESTfull.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class StudentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IStudentRepository _studentRepository;

        public StudentController(IStudentRepository studentRepository)
        {
            _studentRepository = studentRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Student>> GetStudents()
        {
            return await _studentRepository.GetAllStudentsAsync();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> GetStudent(int id)
        {
            var student = await _studentRepository.GetStudentByIdAsync(id);

            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return student;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> PostStudent(Student student)
        {
            await _studentRepository.AddStudentAsync(student);

            return CreatedAtAction("GetStudent", new { id = student.StudentId }, student);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutStudent(int id, Student student)
        {
            if (id != student.StudentId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            await _studentRepository.UpdateStudentAsync(student);

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteStudent(int id)
        {
            var student = await _studentRepository.DeleteStudentAsync(id);

            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
    }
}

IStudentRepository:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RESTfull.Domain.Model;


namespace RESTfull.Infrastructure.Interfaces
{
    public interface IStudentRepository
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<Student>> GetAllStudentsAsync();
        Task<Student> GetStudentByIdAsync(int studentId);
        Task<Student> AddStudentAsync(Student student);
        Task<Student> UpdateStudentAsync(Student student);
        Task<Student> DeleteStudentAsync(int studentId);
    }
}

